# How can I cast a FieldValue.servertimestamp to a sting an upload it to cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`String time = String.valueOf(FieldValue.serverTimestamp());`

Whenever I upload this to the cloud, it doesn't enter it in the desired format.

How can I force the desired format when uploading this data to cloud?

Comment: So what do you need to achieve, you need to add a String representation of the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has own field type called "Timestamp". You can in your class create field type Timestamp with Firestore annotation:

```
@ServerTimestamp
    private Timestamp timeStamp;
```

And leave this field as null, during uploading firestore will automatically fill this field with server timestamp.

I hope it will help